# Energy Utilization in Electromagnetic Actuator Vs Piezo-electric Actuator

Tags: electromagnetism, piezoelectric, efficient-energy-use

Electromagnetic actuators are quite common in almost all industrial and household applicatons. I was wondering that the motion produced by the electromagnetic actuators are the side product of the interaction of electromagnetic fields and not direct conversion electrical energy. On the other hand piezo-electric actuators convert electrical energy directly to actuation much like a comparison between incandesce light bulb vs LEDs. So my question is that why isn't all motors and actuators are being replaced by piezo-electric actuators?

Are electromagnetic actuators more efficient then pieco-electric actuators despite electric energy not being directly converted to motion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

piezoelectric actuators are *high-impedance* devices, which generate power flow as the product of a large *effort variable* with an exceedingly small *flow variable*.

This means that as a piezo crystal flexes in response to an applied voltage, it generates a large force acting through an extremely small distance. The smallness of that actuation distance makes piezo devices almost completely impractical as machine elements that are intended to perform useful work against a load.

the only way to get significant actuation displacement in this case is to build a stack of many, many individual piezo wafers so their displacements add together. But the resulting sum is still a small fraction of an inch.

Comment: Allright so you are suggesting that the displacement from piezo wafers arn't significant enough to be used for industrial grade actuators that require significant displacement that conventional linear actuators provide. Right?

Comment: yes that is right

Comment: thanks, this makes so much sense. Looks like we have been stuck with electromagnetic based actuators for more then four decades, arent there better alternatives yet...

Comment: nope, electromagnetic mechanisms are inexpensive, effective, versatile, and very efficient.